# incorrect watch values in Visual Studio 2017 Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging, c89

In a way this is a duplicate as the question some questions have been asked about the watch window not working under DIFFERENT VERSIONS OF THE SOFTWARE, but not under 2017 so I ask afresh.

My app C++99 and it's using a library I've written part C (C89) and part C++99.  It all compiles and links without warning.

A C file has a global variable, declared extern in its header, of structure type.

When I put a breakpoint in the file with that structure, it appears in the variable watch window as having all-zero contents, despite the function clearly changing variables in it and reacting to those variables.

Other variables, including other file-scoped variables (a static int) display fine, though.

The only unusual thing about this variable is that C++ modules are including the .h file, and I had to put the extern for the variable into the `extern "C"` block along with the C functions.  I tried a conditional compile so that this compilation unit wouldn't see the extern, but that didn't help.  However, if I simply add a second structure named `msDecoy` to the variable definition, Visual Studio can now see the contents of the first variable.  (`msDecoy` is referred to nowhere in the software.)

```
MyStruct_T ms, msDecoy;
```

I've used Visual Studio since 6.0 for a total of say 3-4 man-years, and used 2017 for man-months of work.  I've programmed C/C++ surely 25 man-years at this point.  That is to say, it's not basic unfamiliarity with C or the debugger that is the issue.

I assume it's a Visual Studio bug, but does anyone have an alternate explanation or a better workaround?

Comment: C++ 99? That's 20 years out of date. As for VS 6, things have changes enormously since then. Back then VS 6 was not exactly compatible. VS since 2003 at least offers one of the best and most compliant compilers

Comment: As for the question itself, post the code. You're asking people to *guess* what the code does. It could be a mix up between C and C++ libraries (which are NOT the same). It could be that features used back then are no longer supported. MS hasn't paid much attention to C, only C++, so it could even be that. As I said, C++ isn't just C.

Comment: I don't think you guys noticed the word "since".  I've used 6.0, 2008, and 2017 extensively along with a couple other versions.  My program doesn't require any features newer than C++99.  It's hardly out of date, any more than C89 is.  Part of the code is indeed 20 years old.  It won't run faster or be easier to maintain if re-written so I'm not going to rewrite it.  And VS took forever to support C99 so I wouldn't call it especially compliant.

Comment: @SwissFrank Hi friend, could you share a code sample(After deleting the core code) to help reproduce this issue. You can share it by one-drive link, then we can download and check this issue.